# Behaviour Subject Sidenav Toggle Angular 7 Material

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-material-6

Im using angular material and i have placed the sidenav toggle button in the navbar. I am trying to subscribe to a boolean value to toggle the sidenav.The boolean is to be passed to one of the child components.

My service :

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs'


@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {
    private sidenav$ : BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

    constructor() {
        this.sidenav$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    }
    getData():Observable<boolean> {
        return this.sidenav$.asObservable();
    }

    updateData(data: boolean) {
        this.sidenav$.next(data);
        console.log("Changed toggle",data);

    }
}
```

Im updating the service in the navbar component like:

```
  sidenavtoggle(){
    this.toggleSidenav.emit();
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    console.log("IS OPEN",this.isOpen);
    this.sidenavService.updateData(this.isOpen);

    };
  }
```

I have injected the service and gave it in the providers for the component. Im subscribing to the observable in the child component sidebar component like:

```
  constructor(private sidenavService:SidenavService) {
    this.prepareNavItems();

    this.subsciption=this.sidenavService.getData().subscribe(data=>{
      console.log("RECEIVED DATA",data);
      this.isExpanded=data;
    });

  }
```

The problem is that the data is subscribed only once when the component is loaded,and not changing when the boolean value is changed.HOw do i continuosly listen to changes in the boolean when updateData()
is called?

HTML :

```
<mat-nav-list  >

  <div class="side-bar-btn" [ngClass]="{'is-active': toggle}" (click)="clickEvent($event)">
    <div class="side-bar-btn-box">
      <div class="side-bar-btn-inner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let navItem of navItems" routerLinkActive="sidebarlinkactive" routerLink="{{navItem.link}}" >
    <a routerLinkActive="active">
      <mat-icon mat-list-icon>{{navItem.icon}}</mat-icon>
      <div matLine *ngIf="isExpanded">{{navItem.text}}</div>
    </a>
  </mat-list-item>

</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: show me your html?

Comment: i have updated the html code @SheikAlthaf

Comment: Instead of `BehaviorSubject` why you are not `Input Output` event

Comment: Is your `console.log("RECEIVED DATA",data);` logging the correct value on every `updateData` call ?

Comment: The console.log for RECEIVED DATA is only printing out once when page is loaded first @ashish.gd

Comment: @bhagwattupe Cannot use input,output because i want to pass data to component which is in router outlet

Comment: Usually `constructor` is not a good place for your code. Move it to a lifecycle method like `ngOnInit` also, as suggested below you can get a reference to your observable eg: `isExanded = this.sidenavService.getData()` in your component and then use the `async` pipe in your template. Good thing is `async` pipe take care of unsubscribing when the component is destroyed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `async` pipe and also i have modified to your code some

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs'


@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {
    private sidenavSource$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    sidenav$ = this.sidenavSource$.asObservable();

    updateData(data: boolean) {
        this.sidenavSource$.next(data);
        console.log("Changed toggle",data);

    }
}
```

In your HTML use async pipe

```
constructor(public sidenavService: SidenavService) {} //make the service public

<div matLine *ngIf="sidenavService.sidenav$ | async">{{navItem.text}}</div>

<button (click)="sidenavService.updateData(true)">open</button>
<button (click)="sidenavService.updateData(false)">close</button>
```

Comment: Tried brother,sorry but doesnt work .Changed Toggle is console logging correclty when i togggle using button . But the sidenavService.sidenav$ remains at false

Comment: try to print the data like this and {{navItem.text}} to {{sidenavService.sidenav$.value}}. and check what you have got in value after toggling

Comment: I tried it but with {{sidenavService.sidenav$}}  .It is always printing out false  ..With ".value" .It doesnt print out anything

Comment: {{sidenavService.sidenav$}} is now printing out [Object object']

Comment: I have edited the answer with two buttons. Try that and let me know

Comment: tried.. Changed Toggle is printing out correclty as toggle true and false ..But the sidenavService.sidenav$ stays the same,not working

Comment: I think $sidenav is returning as an observable ,we need to change it to boolean?

Comment: async only needs Observable. no need to change anything. Don't know what is the problem

Comment: could this be an issue with the service? You have done next on sidenav source but not sidenav

Comment: everything is correct. I will create a stackblitz if possible to explain

Comment: Thank you for the stackblitz example. In that,  the data updation and receiving is within the same component. In my case, these are in different components and that too inside one of the component of a router outlet..Does this still work the same way in this case too ?

Comment: make sure your service is root service

Comment: I remember including the service in the components providers.. I'll update you tomorrow.. That might be the issue.. I should place the service inside app.module providers?

Comment: IT worked after i removed the service from the providers of the two components